# How to use the ternary operator in react using javascript styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a piece code for which i am not understanding what this ternary operator means.

below is my code,

```
const mobileWidth = '800'px;
const Width = '1200'px;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: ${props =>
        props.theme.isMobile
            ? props.theme.isPortrait
                ? 'calc(100% - 162px)'
                : mobileWidth
            : Width};
`;
```

could someone help me understand this. thanks.

Comment: Turn it into nested ifs. `if (isMobile) { if (isPortrait) (calc) else { mobileWidth } } else { Width }`

Comment: Try to not nest ternary, there is a linting rule for that for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested ternary operator can be easily hard to read so probably you should arrange it to directly see the different conditions. The logic of it could be represented with the following:

[image]

Comment: "Should be avoided", "Hard to read" are all subjective. Hard to read for who?

Comment: @SamR. eslint for example set by default the rule [no-nested-ternary](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary). Probably there is a good reason for that.

Comment: It's written by somebody like you who decided something totally valid "Should be avoided" because they thought so.

Comment: @SamR. I updated my answer to not give my subjective opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

Ternary [or] Conditional operator - It will take three operands

`condition ? expIFTrue: expIFFalse`

If the condition is evaluated to `true`, the first expression (before the colon) will execute otherwise the second expression (after the colon) will execute.

For this case,

`props.theme.isMobile ? (props.theme.isPortrait? 'calc(100% - 162px)': mobileWidth): Width`

If `isMobile` is evaluated to true, the control will go to the first expression given in the bracket (nothing but another ternary syntax). Again will check for the `isPortrait`condition.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props into styled components ([Styled Components Theming](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced)), in this case let's say we have `theme` state and pass to styled components to set different width for the div for different mobile and portrait states. In styled components,

it will first check if `theme.isMobile` is true, if true it will continue to check if `theme.isPortrait` is true, if it's still true then it will return `calc(..)`. If `theme.isPortrait` is false it will return `mobileWidth`. Then finally if theme.isMobile is false it will return `Width`.

```
const mobileWidth = '800'px;
const Width = '1200'px;
const DivStyles = styled.div`
  width: ${(props) =>
    props.theme.isMobile
      ? props.theme.isPortrait
        ? "calc(100% -162px)"
        : mobileWidth
      : Width };
  height: 200px;
  background: #353535;
`;

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState({
    isMobile: true,
    isPortrait: false
  });
  return <DivStyles theme={theme}></DivStyles>;
}
```